# pdf does not open

Tags: 12.04, pdf, libreoffice

when i create a pdf file from calc (libre office 3.5.3.2) i cannot open that file (with evince 3.4.0 or other pdf viewer) this when the calc file comes from a different computer (ubuntu 12.04 - 64bits) - even after the calc file has been saved on my own computer. This pdf file is anyhow created properly and it can be opened by any other pc - yet it cannot be opened by my own computer.

no problem - i can open the pdf file - when the pdf is from my own created calc file starting from zero.

authorisation conflicts for pdf of ods files coming from different source ?

this after recent updates - this problem has never happened before - i hope next updates will fix this

my system 12.04 - 32bit

thanks

Comment: It could be very helpful is you can upload an example file (both ods and pdf) somewhere and link it here.

Answer (score 2):

i've reinstalled ubuntu 12.04 over previous partition, it's ok now